# Vectorize 3D Logo in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, logo

I am new to Illustrator and vectorizing Logos. I need to vectorize this logo

[image: MSB]

My questions are: how can I find out the two font types and colors? What will be the best way to vectorize this Logo 1:1 in Illustrator? Because I am new to Illustrator it will be helpful if you tell me how to do it.

Comment: Off hand I don't know what font the MSB is, but the subtext is certainly Brush Script: http://i.stack.imgur.com/v6Ks3.png

Comment: Thank you John. Do you know a way how the MSB text font could be identified.

Comment: Try straightening up the image (shear/skew) then run it through [whatthefont](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/)

Comment: @user2008687, I tried straightening it and running it through WhatTheFont, but couldn't see anything that matched. You may want to post it on the forum there. Depending on how handy you are with the Pen tool, it wouldn't be too difficult to just replicate it yourself instead of trying to find the font.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Don't bother with trying Illustrator's 3D effect. It'll take more time than anything.In addition, lighting won't ever be right with the effect.
- simply place the logo in Illustrator, lock the layer it's on. Then create a new layer and manually trace the image.
- The tag line is Brush Script as John points out. So I'd set that in live type.
- I'd personally simply redraw the MSB and not worry about a font. it's only 3 letters and they are fairly easy to recreate

Comment: Thank you very much Scott, I will trace it manually as you suggested.